# Chromebook developer mode Issue

Tags: chromebook

having  a little bit hard time entering the dev mode on my Lenovo 100s Chromebook

after entering the recovery mode, after pressing The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and enabling the risk, the Chromebook is preparing system for developer mode with the loading sign on the left, waiting a couple minutes the screen goes to the "OS VERIFICATION is OFF, waiting about 20 seconds and right after that I am hearing exactly 2 Beeps, and all over again and it repeats the same procedure for about more than 3 hours already and nothing happens to it help anybody?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you successfully entered developer mode. 
Try rebooting your device and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on "OS VERIFICATION OFF" screen. If that does not work, try recovering your device and repeat the same process.

You can refer to this guide: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/debug_buttons.md#firmware-menu-interface